# No implementation found for method getApplicationSupportDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-fonts

it happened when I added google_fonts: ^4.0.3 to my flutter pupspec yaml file.

```
E/flutter ( 4828): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationSupportDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
E/flutter ( 4828): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
platform_channel.dart:313
E/flutter ( 4828): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4828): #1      getApplicationSupportDirectory
path_provider.dart:78
E/flutter ( 4828): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I tried flutter clean, and flutter doctor found no issues.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1555],
    locale en-IN)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc4)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.77.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Comment: what platform are you developing for?

Comment: I'm developing for android